# Password generator, how to make it return strong enough passwords

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I created a simple password generator that is also strength check capable. However, I struggle to decide how it should behave if it fails to generate a strong enough password. At this point, it just displays a creation failure message.

Should I define the password creation rules or just make the function re-launch if the password created is not strong enough? Any remarks, suggestions or leads are appreciated. Thanks.

The code can be found below.

```
'use strict'; 


let generatePassword = function(passwordLength = 10) {

  let alphabetString = "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNMqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890-_=+[]{}!@#$%^&*();:'|\,<.>/?`",
  alphabet = alphabetString.split("",),
  passwordArray = [],

  getRandomSymbol = function() {
    return alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random()*alphabet.length)]
  };

  for (let i = 0; i < passwordLength; i++) {
    passwordArray.push(getRandomSymbol());
  } 

  let password = passwordArray.join(""),
  passwordStrengthCheck = new RegExp("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})");

  if (password.match(passwordStrengthCheck)) {
    return console.log(`Your password is: ${password}`);
  } else {
    console.log("Failed to generate a strong enough password");
  }
}


// Function call sample:

generatePassword();
```

Comment: Unlikely, but if this is *serious* and not just a test, consider looking at https://xkcd.com/936/ if you haven't already

Comment: Regardless, your question doesn't really have a clear problem statement - if the code is already working, if you want somewhat opinion-based answers on how it might be formulated better, it would be more suited to codereview than here

Comment: @CertainPerformance It has a pretty clear problem statement. "How should the program fail if the generated password isn't strong enough". The only sensible solution is to generate a stronger password in response, but it's clear enough.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem to me, what about finding an algorithm that does always generate a strong-enough password? Otherwise, maybe you could "repeat the generation until strong enough"? Have a look at @CertainPerformance link as well ;)

Comment: I suggest to visit the `npm site` and take a module which does this for you. There are plenty! For example => https://www.npmjs.com/package/strong-password-generator

No need to re-invent the wheel!

Comment: I is not about re-inventing, but the learning how to create something like that and just practice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ensure that your password has at least one symbol of all groups, do like that:

1. Pick random char from each group (1 from Capiltal letters, 1 from small, 1 digit ....)
2. Pick rest chars from `all`
3. Shuffle picked chars

code:

```
let generatePassword = function(passwordLength = 10) {

  let capitals = "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM";
  let small = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";
  let digits = "1234567890";
  let symbols = "-_=+[]{}!@#$%^&*();:'|\,<.>/?`",
  let all = capitals + small + digits + symbols;


  getRandomSymbol = function(sourceString) {
    return sourceString[Math.floor(Math.random()*sourceString.length)]
  };


  alphabet = alphabetString.split("",),
  passwordArray = [],

  passwordArray.push(getRandomSymbol(capitals));
  passwordArray.push(getRandomSymbol(small));
  passwordArray.push(getRandomSymbol(digits));
  passwordArray.push(getRandomSymbol(symbols));



  for (let i = 0; i < passwordLength - 4; i++) {
    passwordArray.push(getRandomSymbol(all));
  } 


  shuffle = function (a) {
    for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];
    }
    return a;
  }

  let password = shuffle(passwordArray).join(""),

  passwordStrengthCheck = new RegExp("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})");

  if (password.match(passwordStrengthCheck)) {
    return console.log(`Your password is: ${password}`);
  } else {
    console.log("Failed to generate a strong enough password");
  }
}
```